# Javascript insert new element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a new row from a table when I press enter on input text. from code below when I press enter on input text `name = "desc"` then the new row with an new element just like current row will appear.

```js
document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc').addEventListener('keypress', (e)=> {

const keynum = e.keyCode||e.which;
const name = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-name');
const desc = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc');
const md_tt_tbody = document.querySelector('.md-tt-tbody');

if(keynum === 13 && name.value !== '' && desc.value !== ''){
   const el = ` <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc"></td>
  </tr>`;

document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", el);

   // document.querySelector('.md_tt_tbody').appendChild(el);
}
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead> 
  <tbody class= "md-tt-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

from code above the new row doesn't show from what I want. I want the new row appear just like the current row. I try with `appendchild` too but I get an error I don't know how to insert with multiple element.

Comment: Why did you change the selector from the `.appendChild()` approach? Now you insert the new row after the closing `</td>` of the description, which generates invalid markup.

Comment: hy andreas thx for reply, i dont understand appendChild() or insertAdjacentHTML approach. i just want to know how can i make new row when i press enter just like the current row with an element on it. i try with innerHTML too but it wil change all content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to add a row to the table, after the last row. Here's a solution using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) (so, just one handler needed for the current and all future rows). Note: the deprecated `keyCode`/`which` is replaced by the more modern `[event].key` here.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('md-tt-inp-desc') && evt.key === "Enter") {
    return addRow();
  }
}

function addRow() {
  console.clear();
  const name = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-name');
  const desc = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc');
  const md_tt_tbody = document.querySelector('.md-tt-tbody');

  if (name.value.trim().length > 0 && desc.value.trim().length > 0) {
    const newRow = `
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc"></td>
      </tr>`;

    return document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc')
      .closest("table")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newRow);
  }
  
  console.log("please fill name and description");
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="md-tt-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name" placeholder="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc" placeholder="description"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small adjustment is needed:
you need to find the current `tr`. there are so many solutions but I added an id to this to find it later easily.

```js
       document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc').addEventListener('keypress', (e)=> {
    
          const keynum = e.keyCode||e.which;
          const name = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-name');
          const desc = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc');
          const md_tt_tbody = document.querySelector('.md-tt-tbody');

          if(keynum === 13 && name.value !== '' && desc.value !== ''){
             const el = ` <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc"></td>
            </tr>`;

          document.querySelector('#first-row').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", el);
              
             // document.querySelector('.md_tt_tbody').appendChild(el);
          }


         });
```

```html
 <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead> 
          <tbody class= "md-tt-tbody">
            <tr id="first-row">
              <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: The `onclick` event listener would not be present in the newly added rows. If that is required, The event listener should be bound after adding each row.

Comment: that's right... will fix that part as well

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution for adding a new row plus move focus on the first input that is newly added.

```js
const rowHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('md-tt-inp-desc') && e.key === "Enter") {
    console.clear();
    const name = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-name');
    const desc = document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc');
    const md_tt_tbody = document.querySelector('.md-tt-tbody');

    if (name.value.trim().length > 0 && desc.value.trim().length > 0)
     addRow();
  }
}

document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener("keyup", rowHandler);

const addRow = () => {

    const newRow = `
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc"></td>
      </tr>`;

     document.querySelector('.md-tt-inp-desc')
      .closest("table")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newRow);
      
      var itemIds = document.querySelectorAll('.md-tt-inp-id');
      itemIds[itemIds.length - 1].focus();
  
  console.log("please fill name and description");
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="md-tt-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_id" class="md-tt-inp-id"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="item_name" class="md-tt-inp-name" placeholder="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desc" class="md-tt-inp-desc" placeholder="description"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```